# Swap a word in vim with adjacent quoted word

Tags: vim

I'm dealing with some markdown text right now where having to swap the current word with an adjacent word surrounded in backticks is very common:

For example:

> From the package `net/http`

becomes:

> From the `net/http` package

How would you switch the current word with an adjacent word in backticks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your cursor anywhere on the line type the following: `` 0f`da`bhP ``

You can save it as a mapping using `` :nnoremap <leader>s 0f`da`bhP ``, then call it using `<leader>s`

Or, create a mapping using `` qs0f`da`bhPq ``, then call it using `@s`

1. `0` Go to the start of the line
2. `` f` `` Go to the next `` ` ``
3. `` da` `` Delete around `` ` ``. The deleted text will be in the `"` register
4. `b` Go backwards to the start of the previous word
5. `h` Go on space right (to keep spacing)
6. `P` Paste the test in the `"` register before the cursor

Comment: could the swap mapping recommended in the vim wiki be modified to accommodate this?

:nnoremap <silent> gw "_yiw:s/\(\%#\w\+\)\(\_W\+\)\(\w\+\)/\3\2\1/<CR><c-o><c-l>

Comment: Try `:nnoremap <silent> gw "_yiw:s/(\%#\S\+)(\s\+)(\S\+)/\3\2\1/<CR><c-o><c-l>`. I've just swapped `\w` (word character) for `\S` (non-whitespace character). See `:h /character-classes`

Comment: it almost works, except it becomes "the net/http` `package" when I try to swap. But thanks for your help, I think your comment put me on the right track

Comment: I think that's because when I first posted my last comment I had forgot to change the `\W` in the original regex with `\s`. I edited my comment so try again.

Comment: it keeps saying "pattern not found" until I re-added the backslashes in between the terms like so `nnoremap <silent>   gw "_yiw:s/\(\%#\S\+\)\(\s\+\)\(\S\+\)/\3\2\1/<CR><c-o><c-l>
`
which works! Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ah crud didn't notice that those had gone missing.